# Homeomorphism from $P^2\mathbb{R}$ onto the image of $\mathbb{S}^2$ through the Veronese map

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds

Consider the map $v \colon \mathbb{S}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^6$ defined by
$$ v(x, y, z) = (x^2, y^2, z^2, \sqrt{2}xy, \sqrt{2}yz, \sqrt{2}zx) $$
Furthermore, let $ M := v(\mathbb{S}^2) $ and $P^2\mathbb{R}$ denote the projective plane.

I want to show that the map $v$ defines a homeomorphism $V$ from $P^2\mathbb{R}$ onto $M$.

Well, I know that $P^2\mathbb{R} \cong {\mathbb{S}^2}/{\sim}$ where $(x, y, z) \sim (-x, -y, -z)$. If I somehow manage to prove that $M \cong {\mathbb{S}^2}/{\sim}$, it'd be neat.

Comment: What if you write $$v: \mathbb{S}^2/\pm 1 \to \mathbb{R}^6$$

Comment: I managed to reduce the problem.
By the universal property of the quotient space, $v$ naturally induces a continuous map $V$ on $M$. This is because for any $p \in \mathbb{S}^2$, we note that $p \sim -p \Rightarrow v(p) = v(-p)$. Furthermore if I manage to prove (i) that V is injective, then by noting that $P^2\mathbb{R}$ is compact, as is the image under the continuous canonical projection of a compact, and (ii) $M$ is submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^6$ and hence Hausdorff, I conclude that V is a homeomorphism.
So right now I'm left with proving (i) and (ii), which I'm struggling at doing so.

Comment: @LefebvreLea You do not need to know that $M$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb R^6$ (it is one, but is irrelevant here). In fact **each topological subspace** of $\mathbb R^6$ is Hausdorff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously $v(x,y,z) = v(-x,-y,-z)$. Thus $v$ induces $V : P^2\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^6$  such that $V(P^2\mathbb R ) = M$. Now let us explore what $v(x,y,z) = v(x',y',z')$ means. The first three coordinates show that $x' = (-1)^a x, y' = (-1)^b y, z'= (-1)^c z$ with $a, b, c \in \{0,1\}$. Coordinate no. 4 shows $a = b$, coordinate no. 5 shows $b = c$ and coordinate no. 6 shows $a = c$. Thus $(x,y,z) = \pm (x',y',z')$, i.e. $V$ is injective. Hence $V : P^2\mathbb R \to M$ is a continuous bijection. Since $P^2\mathbb R$ is compact and $M$ is Hausdorff, the map $V$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: That makes complete sense, thank you. I wasn't sure what the injectivity of $V$ meant. 
How do you know beforehand that $M$ is Hausdorff though? I actually have to prove it is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^6$, because then I could assume it is Hausdorff, since in my class we're treating smooth manifolds as Hausdorff spaces (although not all smooth manifolds are Hausdorff).

Comment: @LefebvreLea $M$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^6$ which is Hausdorff.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why you are complicating this way. $v$ is continuous bijective $\Bbb{S^2/\pm 1}\to v(\Bbb{S}^2)$ and $w:[x:y:z]\to \pm (\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}})$ is continuous bijective $\Bbb{P^2(R)\to S^2/\pm 1}$. The composition of both is your homeomorphism:

The inverse of $w$ is obviously continuous, for the inverse of $v$ I would say that $v^{-1}$ gives a continuous function $v(\Bbb{S}^2)\to \Bbb{S^2}/(\pm 1,\pm 1,\pm 1), (a,b,c,d,e,f)\to (\pm\sqrt{a},\pm\sqrt{b},\pm\sqrt{c})$ which implies that $v^{-1}$ is itself continuous.

Comment: I wouldn't say I'm complicating whatsoever. I just wanted to provide a topological argument instead of constructing tedious inverses. Thanks though