# Image of Sphere is a submanifold of $R^6$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, submanifold

I was trying to prove that $\alpha(S^2)$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^6$.

$\alpha(x,y,z) = (x^2, y^2, z^2, \sqrt2 xy, \sqrt2 yz, \sqrt2 zx)$

$\textbf{Attempt}$

I started by proving that  $\alpha(S^2)$ is contained in $S^5$, then I noticed that $S^5$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^6$ in this point can i conclude that $\alpha(S^2)$ is also a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^6$?

If my approach is wrong, I would love some hints!

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4061528) from 3 hours ago. Homework?

Comment: @Karl I was studying LaFontaine's book and come to a stall in a exercise because I had to prove that $\alpha(S^2)$ is a submanifold of $R^6$. What a coincidence!

Comment: Use the definition of a submanifold? Or prove $\alpha$ is an embedding.

Comment: Of course, $\alpha$ is not an embedding, as $\alpha(-\mathbf x) = \alpha(\mathbf x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Verify that $\alpha$ is an immersion and then look at [Homeomorphism from $P^2\mathbb{R}$ onto the image of $\mathbb{S}^2$ through the Veronese map](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4060876) .