# Veronese Surface is a submanifold

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I want to prove that

Consider the map $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to  \mathbb{R}^6$ given by

$$f(x,y,z)=(x^2,y^2,z^2, \sqrt{2} yz, \sqrt{2} xz , \sqrt{2} xy)$$

Then, $f(S^2) \subseteq \mathbb{R^6}$ is a Euclidean submanifold. I want to prove this showing that $f$ is an embbeding. I can prove that $f$ is an immersion, is $f$ an embbeding?

Comment: $f\vert_{S^2}$ is not an embedding of $S^2$, but of $\mathbb{R}P^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true that $f\mid_{S^2}$ is an embedding: We always have $f(-\xi) = f(\xi)$.

However, as user10354138 says in his comment, $f$ induces an embedding $F : \mathbb RP^2 \to \mathbb R^6$. See [Homeomorphism from $P^2\mathbb{R}$ onto the image of $\mathbb{S}^2$ through the Veronese map](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4060876).

Therefore $f(S^2) = F(\mathbb RP^2)$ is a Euclidean submanifold of $\mathbb R^6$.